# Describe 3-colourable graph in propositional calculus

Tags: graph-theory, propositional-calculus

I am trying to solve the following problem.
Let $G=(V,E)$ be a Graph with $V=N$ (natural numbers) and $p_{ij}$ a set of propositional variables for which we have $p_{ij}$ is true <=> $(i,j)\in E$.

I need a set of propositional formulas $\Psi$ based on $p_{ij}$ which have the following property: $\Psi$ are all true $\iff$ $G$ is 3-colourable.

My idea is: $G$ is not 3-colourable if and only if there are $i,j,k,l$ from $V$, so that $(i,j),(j,k),(i,k),(i,l),(j,l),(k,l)$ are all in $E$.
So $\Psi$ would consist of the formulas $\neg (p_{ij} \land p_{jk} \land p_{ik}\land p_{il}\land p_{jl}\land p_{kl})$.

But I'm not sure, it seems somewhat too simple for me.

Could someone help me please?

Comment: Your choice of formulae is unfortunately incorrect: there exist trianglefree graphs with arbitrarily high chromatic number (search for Mycielski's construction for more information on that note), so just checking for a 4-clique is an infeasible approach to this problem.

Comment: But what else can I do? The solution cannot be too difficult also, we had not much theory jet.

Comment: I'm thinking, but it is not obvious to me how to proceed. I'll make a comment or answer here if I figure something out…

Answer (score 2):

According to the [De Bruijn–Erdős theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn%E2%80%93Erd%C5%91s_theorem_(graph_theory)), a graph $G$ is $3$-colourable if and only if every finite subgraph of $G$ is $3$-colourable. Hence, if $V(G)=\mathbb N=\{1,2,3,\dots\},$ then $G$ is $3$-colourable if and only if, for every $n,$ the subgraph $G_n$ induced by $\{1,2,3,\dots,n\}$ is $3$-colourable. I'm sure you can figure out how to construct a formula $\psi_n$ which is true if and only if $G_n$ is $3$-colourable. Then $\Psi=\{\psi_n:n\in\mathbb N\}$ is the set you want.

On second thought, after reading your comment, I'm not so sure you can figure out how to construct a formula $\psi_n$ which is true if and only if $G_n$ is $3$-colourable. Here's one way to construct such a formula. Consider a fixed number $n$ and let $[n]=\{1,2,3,\dots,n\}.$

For each set $X\subseteq[n]$ construct a formula $\alpha_X$ which says that $X$ is independent, i.e., that no two vertices in $X$ are joined by an edge. For example, if $X=\{2,3,5,7\},$ we can take
$$\alpha_X=\neg(p_{2,3}\vee p_{2,5}\vee p_{2,7}\vee p_{3,5}\vee p_{3,7}\vee p_{5,7}).$$

Next, for each partition $\pi$ of $[n]$ into three disjoint sets $R,B,G,$ construct a formula $\beta_\pi$ which says that we get a proper colouring of the graph $G_n$ if we colour the vertices in $R$ red, the vertices in $B$ blue, and the vertices in $G$ green; in other words, $\beta_\pi$ says that $R,B,G$ are independent sets. For example, if $n=9$ and $\pi=\{\{1,3,5,7\},\{2,9\},\{4,6,8\}\},$ we can take
$$\beta_\pi=\alpha_{\{1,3,5,7\}}\wedge\alpha_{\{2,9\}}\wedge\alpha_{\{4,6,8\}}.$$
Finally, list all the partitions of $[n]$ into three parts in a sequence $\pi_1,\pi_2,\dots,\pi_{k(n)}$ where $k(n)$ is the number of such partitions, and let
$$\psi_n=\beta_{\pi_1}\vee\beta_{\pi_2}\vee\cdots\vee\beta_{\pi_{k(n)}}.$$

Of course, the construction of the formulas $\psi_n$ is trivial. The nontrivial part of the problem is the De Bruijn–Erdős theorem; you can find a proof of that at the Wikipedia page.

Comment: Thank You, but I don't see how it helps to consider a finite subgraph. Your idea was clear to me, in fact I sort of used it in my consideration above.

Comment: The De Bruijn–Erdős theorem is not my idea, it is a non-trivial result. Considering finite graphs is certainly helpful; it means that all you have to do is to construct in the obvious way a formuls $\psi_n$ which says that the graph induced by the first $n$ vertices is $3$-colourable, and then (because of the De Bruijn–Erdős theorem) the whole graph will be $3$-colourable if and only if all of the formulas $\psi_n$ are true.

Comment: "The De Bruijn–Erdős theorem is not my idea, it is a non-trivial result."                               Yes, of course. But it is a very well known result. So You can be sure that I knew it already.                                                                                                                                                                            "it means that all you have to do is to construct in the obvious way"                                                                    It is unfortunately not obvious at all for me. And also not for A.Sh (see above).

Comment: Could You please show how to construct the formula $\psi_5$? So for the first 5 vertices?

Comment: Do you still want me to construct $\psi_5$? It will be tedious to type, because it is a disjunction of 25 formulas, one disjunct for each of the 25 partitions: {{1,2,3},{4},{5}}, . . ., {{1,2},{3,4},{5}}, . . ..

Comment: A more brutal way to construct $\psi_n$: list all the $3$-colourable graphs on the vertex set $\{1,2,3,\dots,n\};$ for each such graph $H$ write a formula which says that $G_n=H$; and take the disjunction.

Comment: No, thank You, I understood the idea. But could You please help me on another problem? It's surely easy for You. The Problem is http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1803117/propositional-formulas-for-connected-graph. You already wrote once the answer to this question, it was here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1312872/prove-disconnectedness-of-a-graph-is-not-generalized-first-order-logic-definable. I understand the idea roughly, but i have a difficulty to apply the back-and-forth method as You wrote. Could You please write something more details on this?